# Python - open weather map encode åäö

Tags: python, openweathermap

I got some problems with the letters åäö (\xe4 \xe5 \xe6) when request json from openweathermap. What can I do to encode it the right way?

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


def getSource(city, countrycode):
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city},{countrycode}&appid=xxx".format(city=city, countrycode=countrycode)
    with urlopen(url) as response:
        source = response.read()
    return(source)    

source = getSource("Borås", "se")

data = json.loads(source)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Comment: Does `UnicodeEncodeError` appears during `json.loads` xor `json.dumps`?

Comment: yes. print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an API id, but could you please try parse.quote from urllib, like this:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote 

def getSource(city, countrycode):
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+quote(city)+"{countrycode}&appid=xxx".format(city=city, countrycode=countrycode)
    with urlopen(url) as response:
        source = response.read()
    return(source)    

source = getSource("Borås", "se")

data = json.loads(source)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```